# fast interpolation of a (50000,3000) numpy array along axis=-1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D array of seismic data of shape (50000, 3000)

I need to 1d interpolate everything in axis=-1

If z=values, t0=value times, tx= new times, I'm currently doing

```
for i in range(dataset.size):
    result[i,:] = np.interp(tx[i,:], t0[i,:], z[i,:])
```

not surprisingly it takes hours.

- t0 is sorted but irregularly sampled
- tx is sorted and regularly sampled

any suggestions on significantly speeding up the code?

am limited to numpy/scipy solutions only

Comment: could you supply a little more code, perhaps a minimal working example I can copy/paste into my editor and start playing around with? I need to know what type `dataset` is (a numpy array?) and where `z` comes from. Also, are the rows of `tx` all different? are the rows of `t0` all different?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve. You can use array slicing to interpolate just a small subset of your data, if you know where the interesting region is. Or you may want to see the big picture by using statistical metrics.

I don't think there is a way to significantly speed up the `np.interp()` itself, since it essentially traverses all the points in your data. You can try `interp1d()` from `scipy.interpolate`, but again I think there will be no significant performance difference.

Comment: it's a form of geometrical correction to the seismic data. as such it has to be done to the entire dataset.